# Is there a way of modifying Task Manager's CPU up-time?

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

I want to set it to something crazy like 1 month. Is there a way to do this in Windows 10? Like a memory hack or something.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible (but willing to be proved wrong).

Comment: Leave your machine on a month. I don't have a machine that's been up more than 10 days at the moment, but they tend to get restarted for OS updates, rest of the time they're up, 60 days or so is not unusual.

Comment: ... or photoshop ;) [Real data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRvdL.png)  - [Fake data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcTk2.png)

Comment: Just use an OS that doesn't frequently crash, e.g. 16+ years uptime for a Novell system. https://www.novell.com/communities/coolsolutions/16-years-uptime-can-you-top/, and look for similar for Unix and Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is...

1. turn "set time automatically" off
2. hibernate your computer
3. try to access your bios
4. change date from bios
5. boot again to your windows and see "up-time" in Task Manager

[two years up time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0Ich.png)

Comment: then, you can modify date and time via another os installed on your computer or a live os from a removable disk.

Comment: is there any way to reset the date and time back to the original settings?

Comment: Sure, just turn "set time automatically" back on.